# WinGetPos yields no size or position values

Tags: autohotkey

I can't get a size or position from `WinGetPos` in the following script:

```
!Numpad4::
 MouseGetPos, Xm, Ym, Win
 WinGetPos, Xw, Yw, Ww, Hw, %Win%
 MsgBox "Win ID: %Win% Mouse pos: (%Xm%,%Ym%) Window pos: (%Xw%,%Yw%) size: (%Ww%x%Hw%)"
return
```

Instead, I get

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

From `AutoHotkey` [documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGetPos.htm): '`WinGetPos [, X, Y, Width, Height, WinTitle, WinText, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText]` ... `WinTitle` window title or other criteria identifying the target window'. Your identifying criteria is window's `HWND` value that you got from `MouseGetPos`. So you shoul tell `AutoHotkey` that it is `HWND` and not some other value.

In  `WinGetPos` call put `ahk_id` before `Win` variable. That means that you use `HWND` value to identify the window you work with.

like so:

```
!Numpad4::
MouseGetPos, Xm, Ym, Win
WinGetPos, Xw, Yw, Ww, Hw, ahk_id %Win%
MsgBox "Win ID: %Win% Mouse pos: (%Xm%,%Ym%) Window pos: (%Xw%,%Yw%) size (%Ww%x%Hw%)"
return
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetch position of window specified by windows-id "*Win*":

```
WinGetPos, Xw, Yw, Ww, Hw, ahk_id %Win%
```

You were searching for a window titled "0x130496." You need the keyword **ahk_id** to refer to a window by its id: